# Restkit 0.22.0 how to map a simple JSON response with no keyPath to post

Tags: json, restkit, response, restkit-0.20, rkmappingtest

For simplicity the Rest API, sends this JSON response-body= { "status" : "ok"}.

I set-up my Restkit mappings like... created a Class called StatusResponse which has one `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *status;`

```
RKObjectMapping *statusResponseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[StatusResponse class]];
    [statusResponseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"status":@"status"}]; 

// also tried : [statusResponseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@[@"status"]]; which resulted in same error

    NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

RKResponseDescriptor *statusResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:statusResponseMapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:@"status" keyPath:nil statusCodes:statusCodes];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:statusResponseDescriptor];

I'm running a post which is successful, but I get this error back:

NSUnderlyingError=0x17024d440 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched.", keyPath=null, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded.}
response.body={
  "status": "ok"
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try keyPath to @"" and pathPattern as nil, here is piece of Code I am using which is perfectly working fine for me. I am doing exactly same you are trying to do.

```
RKResponseDescriptor *statusResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[ResponseStatus rkObjectMappingForResponse:YES] method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"" statusCodes:statusCodes];
```

Comment: Apologies for delayed response.  I'm going to try your suggestion.  Thanks for sharing.  I will let you know my results.

Answer (score 0):

Because your response descriptor has `pathPattern:@"status"`, the mapping will only be used when you make a request to the `status` path on your server. That probably isn't what you want.

You should probably use `pathPattern:nil`.

Comment: I have attempted with pathPattern: Nil without success.  I need to know how to create the ObjectMapping for simple JSON object {"status" : "ok"} which does not have a keyPath.  When I simple attempt to with keyPath: @"status" I get error key-value coding violation.  I have been reading  RestKit git wiki on ObjectMapping, but they do not show a how to for this simple case.  Do you have a reference that you could point me to?